# NPM Install is exctracting packages

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, apt-get

Usually it would install the files in a folder but now it seems like it's extacting everything in `node_modules` ? Did I mess something up?

I looked on the internet but I couldn't find the anwser.

Comment: npm install package //local using or using -g for global install you need to install to the local

Comment: @headmax but this is what my node modules folder looks like when it normally would just put in the map, I installed `mysql` here.. https://gyazo.com/048910eabb351f44421049a45c8dd16c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how npm dependency resolution works since version 3, basically for efficiency purposes. For more information have a look at the docs. https://docs.npmjs.com/how-npm-works/npm3

Comment: Ah right, I updated and then it started doing this, I thought I messed something up, thanks for clearifying.